# Modal Footer-Ajax message centering in the modal footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this modal footer with a `<label></label>` which displays message on successful operation. But, the properties are inherited so the style for centering is not working. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <label type="text" id="resultmessage" style="color: white; vertical-align:middle;"></label>
    <button type="button" id="updateWorksStatus" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update Status</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add more info about what you want to happen and what is currently happening? A screenshot or JSFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit A StackOverflow inline snippet would be better than a JSFiddle

Comment: HaveSpacesuit - I have added the screenshot. The message "Database Updated" is to be centered in the Modal Footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a more specific CSS selector to override bootstrap styles (`.modal-footer` is set to `text-align: right` by default.).

```
div.modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also, you can switch label order to last element inside of `.modal-footer` if you wish for it to be on the right side of buttons (changed color to gray just for visibility).

Snippet:

```css
div.modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="updateWorksStatus" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update Status</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <label type="text" id="resultmessage" style="color: gray; vertical-align:middle;">Database updated</label>
</div>
```

**If you wish to only center the message, you can do (tweak values to your benefit):**

```css
.modal-footer button {
  margin-top: -48px;
}

#resultmessage {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal-footer">
  <label type="text" id="resultmessage" style="color: gray; vertical-align:middle;">Database updated</label>
  <button type="button" id="updateWorksStatus" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update Status</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using label as not label for nothing is not good pratice. I'm quessing that u want this information ('Database updated') aligne vertically (you have tried to use vertical-align - it only works for tables). Instead of using **label**, better is to use for example **span**.

I did it like below:

https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/BdWbjg

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<span id="resultmessage">Database updated</span>
<div class="tools">
<button type="button" id="updateWorksStatus" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update Status</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS (edited)**

```
.modal-footer {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;


flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#resultmessage {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tools {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: My bad. I was trying for vertical as well as horigzonal alingment to Middle and Center, Respectively.

Comment: @RakySharma check my eddited CSS

Comment: Czeran It is working good. But then the height of the footer has reduced causing the buttons top overflowing into Modal body, Display wise. But Yes sir, its working good and I will take on from here. Thanks for all the effort.